# Which is a better way of serving files (for downloads) via Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, download

If a file is available to me a byte-array, which method would be better to enable the users to download the file?

A: Write the byte-array directly to response stream using Apache IOUtils. In this case, what will happen if the client stops the download and/or is disconnected? I want to keep the JVM's memory utilization to a minimum.

B: Write the byte-array to a file in some temporary location. Then get a FileInputSteam and write that to the response. In this case I would need to write code to manage the saved files on the disk and ensure periodic cleanup. The cleanup algorithm would need to ensure that it does not try to delete a file which is currently being served to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case where I think there's no one-size-fits-all:

- What size are all your byte-arrays? (average, min/max)
- Do you read them from disk anyways?
- How long does a byte-array typically survive in memory once you have it
- How often do you observe connection interruptions compared to successful and full downloads? On which file sizes?
- Did you measure what happens when you just stream the bytes that you have anyways?
- Do many users download the same content at the same time?

As you state you have the files in byte-arrays anyway, I'd not expect it to be prohibitive to serve exactly that byte-array. However, you'll need to be aware of the encoding of the byte-array (assuming that it's textual content, you'll need to send an encoding header with the response)

Without measuring what your situation is, there's hardly any reasonable recommendation for what you should do.

**Edit, Replying to your comment**: Whenever a request has been handled - e.g. when the file has been fully transmitted or when a "broken pipe" exception was thrown, I'd assume that your memory will be freed, unless you explicitly save it in the webapp's session or in any other datastructure that survives for longer. But you probably won't do that explicitly, right?

The sizes and nature of your downloads don't seem like you have really high demand on either I/O or memory. My advice: Don't worry. However, what you should do is: Measure. Check if memory consumption is indeed a problem. I doubt that it is. If it's not broken: Don't fix it.

You have the byte array anyway - you might as well use it to stream it to the client and only then forget about it. It doesn't look like this would take prohibitively long.

Comment: Answering your questions: The data is generally around 1~5 MBs and the max can be 15MB. I am getting data from Amazon S3 and then converting it to a byte array because a decryption program needs it. All this happens when a user requests a particular file i.e. an HTTP GET. I don't expect connection interruptions but I want to avoid any memory leak or wastage. I don't expect many users to download the same content at the same time.

Comment: Edited my answer. TL;DR: Don't worry, unless you measure and can prove that you have a problem.